# How to create sql procedure for reporting from two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

i have two tables called shipment and payment with the following columns

Shipment

```
1.Executivename
2.shipername
3.shiperaddress
4.acountno
5.invoiceno 
6.shipdate  
etc.
```

Payment

1.InvoiceNo
   2.accountno
   3.Date
   4.Discount
   5.ReceivedAmount
   6.MoneyReceiptNo

Now I want to generate report by Executive name with the field of "Payment" table.I tried to do that by following Stored procedure-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptexecutivepayment] @executivename varchar(20) AS 
BEGIN 
    select Executivename,[shipment].accountno,[date],discount,receivedamount,moneyreceiptno
    from shipment 
    full join payment on shipment.accountno=payment.accountno and shipment.invoiceno=payment.invoiceno 
    where Executivename=@executivename order by Executivename 
END
GO
```

But, the report r generating data duplication. What can i do now? Please, somebody help me.

Comment: Using a stored procedure for this is like using a sledge hammer to nail a tack.  Add the tables to the report and link them instead.  Seriously, don't use stored procedures for reporting!

Answer (score 0):

poor schema...

** Shipment table must have 
shipmentno 
invoiceno
othershipmentdetails..

**Invoice Table must have
InvoiceNo
AccountNo
otherInvoiceDetails..

**AccountMaster table must have
AccountNo
AccountDetails...

that's a nomarlized schema and wont hinder you from doing reports.